# Order jqgrid by data that is not loaded into the grid?

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

When using jqgrid you can set the select statement via:

```
$grid->SelectCommand = $query
```

However you cannot set the `ORDER BY` here.

jqgrid allows you to sort the grid on any column.

If my DB table has a column called "cost" and I want my grid to be in order by cost but NOT show cost. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can include on your html page an additional element like checkbox or a select with options which allows the user to choose the sort order. To read information about users selection you can use

```
var addSortInfo = jQuery("#orderByCost").is(':checked');
```

or

```
var addSortInfo = jQuery("#selectList option:selected").val();
```

Then you can use [postData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option of jqGrid to send additional data with all requests to the server. The value of the `postData` parameter can be an object like `{mySortInfo: addSortInfo}` where "mySortInfo" is the name of additional parameter which you will see on the server side together with `sidx`, `page` and other standard parameters of every requests. In case of HTTP GET requests the data from `postData` will be appended to the server url and in case of HTTP POST the data will be added to the request body.

You can also use functions inside of `postData`. The advantages of this approach you can read in  [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In your DB select statement you can select the data to return based on the order by cost or you can include cost as a column in your jqgrid and set it to hidden and order by the cost column.